# Start up and shut down issue after software update

Tags: update-manager, shutdown, startup

These two programs updated yesterday. I am now, when starting up or shutting down, I no longer see the the Ubuntu splash screen. Instead I am seeing a rundown of the start-up and shut down operations. Is this indicating a problem? Everything seems to be operating normally.

```
Start-Date: 2015-01-13  12:30:24
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.68'
Install: linux-headers-3.13.0-44:amd64 (3.13.0-44.73), linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-44.73), linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-44.73), linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-44.73)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.43.50, 3.13.0.44.51), libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.7, 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.8), openssl:amd64 (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.7, 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.8), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-43.72, 3.13.0-44.73), linux-image-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.43.50, 3.13.0.44.51), linux-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.43.50, 3.13.0.44.51)
End-Date: 2015-01-13  12:32:29
```

Comment: Whether you will see the splash screen or not is determined by the parameter GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in `/etc/default/grub`. If the word "splash" occurs in the command line, then you will see a splash screen, otherwise you won't. But in neither case does it indicate a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Good to know this is not a problem.

Comment: @Jos: you should convert this to an answer...  (And if you don't, I will!)  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you will see the splash screen or not is determined by the parameter GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in `/etc/default/grub`. If the word "splash" occurs in the command line, then you will see a splash screen, otherwise you won't. But in neither case does it indicate a problem.

Comment: Thanks Jos! Just wanted to be sure this was not a sign of a larger problem.